# vectorizing a non-explicit function in Matlab and Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I want to vectorize a 3D function, but the function does not have an analytical expression.  For instance, I can vectorize the function

```
 F(x, y, z) = (sin(y)*x, z*y, x*y)
```

by doing something like

```
 function out = Vect_fn(x, y,z)
     out(1) = x.*sin(y);
     out(2) = z.*y;
     out(3) = x.*y;
 end
```

And then running the script

```
 a = linspace(0,1,10);
 [xx, yy, zz] = meshgrid(a, a, a);
 D = Vect_fn(xx, yy, zz)
```

However, suppose the function does not have an analytical expression, for example

```
 function y = Vect_Nexplicit(y0)
      %%%%%%y0 is a 3x1 vector%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      t0 = 0.0; 
      tf = 3.0;
      [t, z] = ode45('ODE_fn', [t0,tf], y0);
      sz = size(z);
      n = sz(1);
      y = z(n, :);
 end
```

where `ODE_fn` is just some function that spits out the right-hand side of a an ODE.  Thus the function simply solves an ODE and so the function is not known explicitly.  Of course I can use a `for` loop, but those are slower (esp. in Octave, which I prefer since it has `lsode` for solving ODEs)

Trying something like

```
a = linspace(0,1,10);
 [xx, yy, zz] = meshgrid(a, a, a);
 D = Vect_Nexplicit(xx, yy, zz)
```

does not work.  Also here is the code for ODF_fn:

```
 function ydot = ODE_fn(t, yin)

 A = sqrt(3.0);
 B = sqrt(2.0);
 C = 1.0;

 x = yin(1, 1);
 y = yin(2,1);
 z = yin(3, 1);

 M = reshape(yin(4:12), 3, 3);

 ydot(1,1) = A*sin(yin(3)) + C*cos(yin(2));
 ydot(2,1) = B*sin(yin(1)) + A*cos(yin(3));
 ydot(3,1) = C*sin(yin(2)) + B*cos(yin(1));

 DV = [0 -C*sin(y) A*cos(z); B*cos(x) 0 -A*sin(z); -B*sin(x)      C*cos(y) 0];

 Mdot = DV*M;

 ydot(4:12,1) = reshape(Mdot, 9, 1);


 end
```

Comment: if there is no analytical solution and you have to solve a differential equation for every new input, I don't see how it's possible with some kind of loop construction. (arrayfun etc in matlab is essentially also a loop)

Comment: I think your current approach might work if `ODE_fn` is properly vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve systems of differential equations with ode45, so if ODE_fn is vectorised you can use your approach. y0 just needs to be a vector too.

You can create a y0 that is [x1, ..., xn, y1, ..., yn, z1, ..., zn, M1_1-9, ... ,Mn_1-9] and then use for x, y, z just the appropriate indexes i.e. 1:n, n+1:2*n, 2*n+1:3n. Then use reshape(yin(3*n+1:end),3,3,n). But I am not sure how to vectorize the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks.  It might be a bit difficult to vectorize my specific form of ODE_fn, but I can try.  Also good to know about t0 and tf.

Comment: Just see it as a system of uncoupled differential equations.

Comment: Uncoupled is not the right word.  For 2D equations uncoupled means (xdot, ydot) = (f(x), g(y)).  Note that the system (xdot, ydot) = (f(x, y),g(x, y)) is not uncoupled.  What I have is even a bit more complicated since I am evolving a matrix...

Comment: I added ODE_fn in my original post

Comment: I just realised not t0 and tf need to be vectors but y0. And you should create a uncoupled system of equations. I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your answer is then the same as Isaac from July 27 (see above).  Also, as I mentioned, it seems your use of the word uncoupled is wrong.  Certainly every ODE can be written as a system, but in most equations the system is coupled and there is no way to write it as an uncoupled system

Comment: If you want to vecotrise multiple calls of odex you can create a larger partially uncouple system to gain speed of vectorisation. It does not matter if your previous system is coupled or not you just use many of them in 'parallel'.